# Conditionally execute block in Ruby if value is not nil? (aka Smalltalk's ifNotNilDo:)

Tags: ruby, design-patterns, block, smalltalk

In Smalltalk there is the method `ifNotNilDo:`
It is used like this:

```
database getUser ifNotNilDo: [:user | Mail sendTo: user ]
```

On objects that are not `nil` the block is executed, passing the object itself as a parameter. The implementation in class `UndefinedObject` (Smalltalk's equivalent of Ruby's `NilClass`) simply does nothing. That way, if getting the user resulted in a `nil` object, nothing would happen.

I am not aware of something similar for Ruby, so I rolled out my own solution.
It goes like this:

```
class Object
  def not_nil
    yield(self)
  end
end

class NilClass
  def not_nil
    # do nothing
  end
end
```

It could be used like this:

```
users = {:peter => "peter@peter.com", :roger => "roger@roger.com" }
users[:roger].not_nil {|u| Mail.send(u) }
```

This saves us from accessing the hash twice

```
Mail.send(users[:roger]) if users[:roger]
```

... or using a temp-variable:

```
u = users[:roger]
Mail.send(u) if u
```

### Update:

People are starting to suggest solutions based on hash-operations, and also accessing the hash twice. My question is not directly hash-related.

Imagine instead that the first operation is not a hash-access and also expensive. Like:

```
RemoteUserRepo.find_user(:roger).not_nil {|u| Mail.send(u) }
```

(end-of-update)

My questions are:

- Am I wrong to re-invent this idiom?
- Is there something like this (or *better*) supported in Ruby out-of-the-box?
- Or is there another, shorter, *more elegant* way to do it?

Comment: I'd personally go with `Mail.send(users[:roger]) if users[:roger]`. Accessing the hash twice shouldn't be that big of a deal in most situations

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In ActiveSupport there is `try` method.
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/try.rb

```
data = { a: [1,2,3] }
data[:a].try(:first)
#=> 1
data[:b].try(:first)
#=> nil
data[:b].first
#=> Exception
```

Under the hood it is implemented close to yours solution. For any object but nil it will "send a message" (in terms of Smalltalk) with attributes.

```
# object.rb
def try(*a, &b)
  if a.empty? && block_given?
    yield self
  else
    public_send(*a, &b) if respond_to?(a.first)
  end
end

# nilclass
def try(*args)
  nil
end
```

About your questions

*Am I wrong to re-invent this idiom?*

Rails guys have made something similar

*Is there something like this (or better) supported in Ruby out-of-the-box?*

No, Ruby doesn't support it out-of-the-box

*Or is there another, shorter, more elegant way to do it?*

In my opinion it has a problem: programmer should control data. One should know what kind of data he has and handle each type and each case, or raise an error. In your case it is valid for all data types but NilClass. What can lead to bugs that will very hard to debug.

I prefer to use old-fashioned

```
Mail.send(users[:roger]) if users[:roger]
# or
users[:roger] && Mail.send(users[:roger])
# or use caching if needed
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my questions. It seems that `try` it *can* be used like in my approach... Pity it's Rails-only though...

Comment: `try` has nothing to do with Rails. It's in `ActiveSupport`.

Comment: You might want to mention the important change in `try` from Rails3 to  Rails4: `try` used to just hide `nil` checks but now it also suppresses `NoMethodError`s from non-`nil` receivers, there is `try!` if you want just the v3 behavior.

Answer (score 22):

In Ruby 2.3.0+, you can use the safe navigation operator (`&.`) in combination with `Object#tap`:

```
users[:roger]&.tap { |u| Mail.send(u) }
```

Comment: you're right. Sorry for the mistake, I deleted my comment to avoid confusing other people.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `tap` to avoid two Hash accesses:

```
users[:roger].tap { |u| Mail.send(u) if u }
```

I might use something like this:

```
[ users[:roger] ].reject(&:nil?).each { |u| Mail.send u }
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning `tap`. Didn't know about it.

Answer (score 2):

In functional languages like Ruby there's an idiomatic solution that takes advantage of the fact that assignment statements return values that can be tested:

```
unless (u = users[:roger]).nil?
  Mail.send(u)
end
```

You thus avoid the extra hash lookup, as desired.  (Some functional purists disapprove of this sort of thing, however, as it tests the return value of a side-effecting statement.)

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Seems cool. What would be the scope of `u`? Does it exist after the `end`?

Comment: Conditionals (`if`, `unless`) don't create a scope in Ruby, so `u` will just be a local in whatever the present lexical scope is and will still have a binding after the `end`.

Comment: Yes, the `u` will continue to exist after the `end`.. which is one of the main reasons I would tend to prefer `tap` in this situation.

Comment: You don't need 'nil?' in condition

Comment: In the most general case, one does need the `nil?` in the condition, to distinguish `false` and `nil` returns.

Comment: Almost a decade later, here I am learning that Ruby conditional blocks don't create scope.  I hadn't noticed! Thanks for pointing that out, @Alp!

Answer (score 2):

No, you are not wrong to re-invent this idiom. You might still do better to give it a more accurate name, perhaps `if_not_nil`.

Yes, there is a core Ruby way to do this, though it's not exactly oozing with elegance:

```
[RemoteUserRepo.find_user(:roger)].compact.each {|u| Mail.send(u)}
```

Recall that `compact` returns an array's copy with the `nil` elements removed.

Comment: Reminds me of Scala's Option, which is to be treated as an array of maximum 1 element. You then eventually access the element with "map" or "foreach". Makes sense, but never totally liked it.

Comment: That Scala thing sounds like a pretty neat way to implement Option! Makes it trivial but unambiguous to deal with Option(Option(MyType)) as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
users.delete_if { |_, email| email.nil? }.each { |_, email| Mail.send email }
```

or

```
users.values.compact.each { |email| Mail.send email }
```

Comment: `delete_if` will mutate original array what can case some problems. Use `select`/`reject` instead